# My jupyter notebook cannot assign instance attributes, all am using is just class object attributes

Tags: python

[I have been trying this many times but it does not work
when I call an instance with the attribute breed, I get an error that an attribute breed is not available !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs0P8.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please avoid posting images, and rather copy and paste the code itself into the question, so that it can be easily copy-pasted by other people

Comment: thanks @Anubhav Gupta, am new at StackOverflow I will work on your advice

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget to pass argument(s)

```py
class Foo():
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = x
            self.y = y

f = Foo(1, 2)
f.x # 1
f.y # 2
```

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 0):

There are the following faults

```py
class Cat: # No paranthesis here
    def __init__(self, breed): # use double underscores
        self.breed = breed
```

In your code, the breed attribute is not created as you have written `_init_` instead of `__init__`, but now it will be created and the error that the attribute isn't available will be resolved.

Secondly,

```py
my_cat = Cat('Scottish Fold') # You need to pass the argument
```